# Get total number of pages of report in VBA ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a button on a form, on its click my report is generated. In the `Load` event of that report I am trying to get Total number of pages. I need them in my DB, but whenever I try `Me.Pages`, I only get 1 in Load Event.

I tried this doing with `Current` and `Activate` event of report as well, but I always get total pages 1.
Any solution?

Comment: @Andre451 any solution?

Comment: I am trying to make table of contents for different reports in MS Acess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access avoids calculating `Pages` unless absolutely necessary, because it's an expensive operation - the whole report must be formatted in advance to get the total number of pages.

To get it, you need to have a Textbox control with `ControlSource` = `=[Pages]` in the **report header**. The Textbox can be invisible. If you don't have a report header currently, create one - it can have a tiny height.

Then you can read `Me.Pages` in the `Format` event of the report header. But you still have to take care, in my example report the event fires twice, and only the second time the actual Pages are returned. And `FormatCount` doesn't work for me.

This code

```
Private Sub Berichtskopf_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)

    Debug.Print "Header_Format, FormatCount = " & FormatCount & ": " & Me.Pages

End Sub

Private Sub Report_Load()

    Debug.Print "Load: " & Me.Pages

End Sub
```

gives this result:

```
Load: 0
Header_Format, FormatCount = 1: 0
Header_Format, FormatCount = 1: 65
```

65 is the correct number.

Comment: Let me try this event of report header

Comment: I did this work in an report event called Report_Page(), it gives me the correct page number as above but it always fire at the end of every thing I want to load another report that is my table of content,
I have a scenario I have number of reports e.g A, B, C, D. I thought to calculate the total number of pages of each report and I got A=2, B=5, C=3, Now the starting page number for Report B should be 3(B=A+1) and I want this 3 in Database but the event you mentioned always triggers at the end of every thing

Comment: I hope you understabd this, basically I am trying to make table of content parallel to these report A, B, C, D. so the report name and starting page number should be in table of content

Comment: However the answer you gave me first should be marked as answer as it states the solution of my question.

Comment: Why don't you use `ReportHeader_Format()`? `Report_Page()` is supposed to do just that, fire on every page.

Comment: Yes you are right now I am using ReportHeader_Format()

Answer (score 0):

My Form has a print button and once pressed a warning comes up about the number of pages in the report... which the user can select yes or no to print.

You can use `Reports(stDocName).Pages` or the `DCount` method to sum pages...
I used the former.: (Make sure the report has a text box with the control properties set to `=Pages` for the former method.

```
Private Sub cmdPrint2_Click()

Dim stDocName As String
stDocName = "RPT_Purchases2"

DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewPreview, , , acHidden
Msg ="There are " & Reports(stDocName).Pages & " Pages to be printed." & (Chr(13)_ 
& Chr(10)) & (Chr(13) & Chr(10)) & "Do you want to continue?"      

Style = vbYesNo + vbInformation
Title = "Total Pages ... "
Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
If Response = vbYes Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewPreview, , , acHidden
    DoCmd.PrintOut
    MsgBox ("Printing")
    Beep
Else
    MsgBox ("Print Job Canceled")
End If

Me.Refresh

End Sub
```